# Get tchart coordinate value on mouse move/clicked/mouse down

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to know how to get coordinate value when my mouse click or move on chart,

I have use this code but trouble with Axes

[Get X and Y values under mouse pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441029/get-x-and-y-values-under-mouse-pointer)

```
procedure TForm2.Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  XVal: double;
  YVal: double;
begin
  XVal:=Chart1.Axes.Bottom.CalcPosPoint(X);
  YVal:=Chart1.Axes.Left.CalcPosPoint(Y);

  Chart1.Title.Text[0]:=FormatFloat('#.##', XVal) + ' - ' + FormatFloat('#.##', YVal);
end;
```

did that code need uses?

what i really need, if i press button 1, get coordinate started, then when i click on chart get coordinate stop and value lock on my edittext

Answer (score 0):

Probably it depends on TChart/TeeChart version.

This works for me:

```
  XVal:=Chart1.BottomAxis.CalcPosPoint(X);
  YVal:=Chart1.LeftAxis.CalcPosPoint(Y);
```

P.S. `what i really need` is not quite clear